# How to generate numbers upto 18 digits, sum of whose reciprocals is a whole number

Tags: c, algorithm

I am looking for a way to generate a series of numbers whose sum of reciprocals is a whole number?

For eg - 11  (1/1 + 1/1 = 2 is a whole number), 122 (1/1+1/2+1/2 is a whole number), 236 (1/2 + 1/3 + 1/6 is a whole number)
and likewise.

Also I want to avoid repeat of same combination or permutation of digits. For example, if 122 is printed, I don't want to print 212 and 221.

I want to know how to approach this problem

Comment: How about a naive approach at the very least? Check every number if is satisfying the condition.

Comment: SO is not for doing your homework for you.

Answer (score 3):

Some thoughts to get you started:

- Your number can't contain zeros.
- You can always add ones to a valid number and it will still be valid.
- You don't need to generate numbers. Generate lists of digits instead. If you keep the list in ascending order, you will automatically solve to problem of how to eliminate permutations.
- Each of the true fractions 1/2 to 1/9 can be represented as an expanded  fraction with the common denominator 2520.

So the following approach might work:

- Start with an empty array and the sum 0.
- Now call your generating function recursively. In each recursion, check wether the sum is divisible by 2520 without remainder. If so, print that number, and also print all numbers padded with ones at the front until you have 18 digits. So for 236 print 236, 1236, 11236 and so on until 111 111 111 111 111 236.
- If your array has length 18, don't recurse further. Otherwise, call your function after adding each of the digits 2 to 9 to your list, but don't use digits that are smaller than the last digit in the list to keep the list sorted.
- Don't recalculate the sum, but instead keep a running sum: When you recurse, add the corresponding numerator to the sum: 1260 for 2, 840 for 3, 630 for 4 and so on.

This bottom-up approach is a lot faster than examining all possible numbers. The following program will print all 14,137 valid numbers (unordered, i.e. in order of generation) in the fraction of a second:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define NDIGIT 18

void rec(int set[], int n, int sum)
{
    static int num[10] = {
        0, 2520, 1260, 840, 630, 504, 420, 360, 315, 280
    };

    if (sum % 2520 == 0) {
        for (int j = 0; j < NDIGIT - n + 1; j++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < j; i++) putchar('1');
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) putchar(set[i] + '0');
            putchar('\n');
        }
    }

    if (n < NDIGIT) {
        int i0 = n ? set[n - 1] : 2;

        for (int i = i0; i < 10; i++) {
            set[n] = i;
            rec(set, n + 1, sum + num[i]);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int set[NDIGIT];

    rec(set, 0, 0);

    return 0;
}
```

If you need sorted output, convert the `set` to a long integer, perhaps `uint64_t` from `<stdint.h>` and store it in an array instead of printing them right away. Then sort the array and print the numbers.

Answer (score 1):

First, you have nine possible digits (because `0` does not lead to a valid fraction), whose reciprocals have a common divisor 2×2×2×3×3×5×7 = 2520:

```
1 -> 1/1 = 2520/2520
2 -> 1/2 = 1260/2520
3 -> 1/3 =  840/2520
4 -> 1/4 =  630/2520
5 -> 1/5 =  504/2520
6 -> 1/6 =  420/2520
7 -> 1/7 =  360/2520
8 -> 1/8 =  315/2520
9 -> 1/9 =  280/2520
```

Therefore, we can use `x/2520` to describe the exact value of such sum. The sum is an integer, if and only if `x` is a multiple of `2520`. We can use the [modulo operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) for this: if `x % 2520 == 0`, the fraction x/2520 represents an integer.

In practice, we don't need to represent the value of the fraction at all, we only need to remember the numerator modulo 2520, `x % 2520`!

Let's look at the algorithm that checks whether the sum of the reciprocals of each digits is a whole number, in pseudocode:

```
Constant Array  per_digit_2520[10] = {
    0,    /* 0 -> 0/1 =    0/2520 */
    2520, /* 1 -> 1/1 = 2520/2520 */
    1260, /* 2 -> 1/2 = 1260/2520 */
    840,  /* 3 -> 1/3 =  840/2520 */
    630,  /* 4 -> 1/4 =  630/2520 */
    504,  /* 5 -> 1/5 =  504/2520 */
    420,  /* 6 -> 1/6 =  420/2520 */
    360,  /* 7 -> 1/7 =  360/2520 */
    315,  /* 8 -> 1/8 =  315/2520 */
    280,  /* 9 -> 1/9 =  280/2520 */
}

Function corresponds_to_whole_fraction(digits):
    Let remain = 0

    For each digit d in digits:
        remain = (remain + per_digit_2520[d]) % 2520 
    End For

    If remain == 0:
        Return "Yes, the digits represent a whole fraction"
    Else:
        Return "No, the digits do not represent a whole fraction"
    Fi

End Function
```

In the loop above, you can also check if digit `d` is zero, and if so, reject the set of digits.

By writing the above, we can immediately notice that because the order of the fractions in the sum does not change the sum, all combinations of a number yield the exact same sum of reciprocal digit fractions.

In other words, if 236 yields a whole sum (it does, because 1/2 + 1/3 + 1/6 = (1260 + 840 + 420)/2520 = 2520/2520 = 1), then also 326, 362, 623, and 632 yield the same sum. Each number is an unique [permutation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation) of the set of digits. To explore permutations further, we need to look at [combinatorics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorics).

Fortunately, the `corresponds_to_whole_fraction()` is simple enough that it is reasonable to generate the desired numbers by generating ordinary numbers, either sequentially or with a random number generator (for numbers with up to 18 digits, I recommend [xorshift64star()](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xorshift#xorshift.2A), since 2<sup>64</sup> > 10<sup>18</sup>).

Let's consider the sequential case:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>

const unsigned int num_2520[10] = {
    0, 2520, 1260, 840, 630, 504, 420, 360, 315, 280
};

int is_acceptable(uint64_t value)
{
    unsigned int  remain = 0;

    if (!value)
        return 0;

    while (value > 0) {
       const unsigned int  digit = value % 10;

       if (!digit)
           return 0;

       value /= 10;
       remain = (remain + num_2520[digit]) % 2520;
    }

    return (remain == 0);
}

uint64_t next_number(uint64_t previous)
{
    while (++previous)
        if (is_acceptable(previous))
            return previous;

    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    uint64_t  value = 0;

    while (1) {
        value = next_number(value);
        if (!value)
            break;

        printf("%" PRIu64 "\n", value);
    }

    /* Never reached */
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The above program prints all numbers between `1` and 2<sup>64</sup>-1 = `18446744073709551615`, inclusive, whose sum of reciprocal digits is a whole number. There are too many of them for anyone to wait long enough for all of them to be printed.

The density is about 0.05% - 0.1% around ten digits, i.e. on average, every one-thousandth (or one two-thousandth) number is acceptable (although there is a lot of variation). So, if you start from a random number, you might wish to check the consecutive numbers starting at that random number, rather than try all new random numbers each time (because random number generators are not very fast in the first place).

If you wanted to limit the above to 18-digit numbers, start with `uint64_t value = UINT64_C(99999999999999999);` (seventeen nines), and replace the `if (!value)` with `if (value > UINT64_C(999999999999999999))` (eighteen nines).